# Node.js - Como ler input do usuário pelo console?

Tags: node.js

Em Java:

```
System.out.println("Diga algo: ");
Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
String resp = leitor.nextLine(); //ou nextInt, nextDouble, etc
```

Em C++

```
cout << "Diga algo: ";
string name;
cin >> name;
```

Como ler input pelo console no Node.js?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Usando o módulo [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html):

```
var readline = require('readline');
var resp = "";

var leitor = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

leitor.question("Qual módulo pra ler dados no node.js?\n", function(answer) {
    var resp = answer;
    console.log("\nSua resposta '" + resp + "' foi grava com sucesso numa variável inútil");
    leitor.close();
});
```

Comment: Para o exemplo que tem que apenas precisa de saber o modulo a ler dados seria provavelmente melhor obter essa informação através de argumentos de entrada do programa.

Answer (score 6):

```js
    
process.stdin.on('readable', ()=>{ 
  // reads what is being typed. 
  let variable = process.stdin.read(); 
  // trying to read 
  variable = variable.toString().replace(/\n/, ""); 
  variable = variable.replace(/\r/, ""); });

// Hope this helps
```