# Como pedir entrada do usuário em Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou tendo problemas em utilizar a função `prompt` no Node.js. Pretendo receber o valor que um usuário desejar para verificação e resolução do meu código. Mas, ao rodar o código, recebo este erro:

> ```
> ReferenceError: prompt is not define
> ```

Meu código é:

```
var distance = prompt("Digite aqui a distância");

if (distance >= 6 && distance <= 800008) {
    console.log("distância aprovada");
}
```

Se não for possível a utilização da função `prompt`, qual poderá substituir?

Comment: `prompt` é um método do objeto `window` nos navegadores. E que contexto seria este `prompt`, node ou browser?

Comment: o contexto seria no node

Comment: Nesse caso, use algum pacote do npm para chegar ao mesmo comportamento esperado em navegadores. Recomento o [pacote prompt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Node.js - Como ler input do usuário pelo console?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286546/node-js-como-ler-input-do-usu%c3%a1rio-pelo-console)

Answer (score 6):

Ao contrário de *browsers*, que expõem uma função no objeto global chamada `prompt`, o Node.js não a implementa.

Para pedir uma entrada do usuário, você pode utilizar o módulo `readline`, do próprio Node.js. Veja um exemplo:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Qual o seu nome? ', (name) => {
  console.log(`Olá, ${name}!`);
});
```

Repare que, ao contrário de `prompt`, que é síncrono nos *browsers* (e bloqueia o *event loop*), o método `question` é assíncrono.

Você também pode converter esse método para a interface de promessas utilizando a função [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original), disponível no módulo `util`. Assim:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

// Utilize `question` com a interface de promessas...
const question = promisify(rl.question).bind(rl);
```

<sup>Observe que omiti a definição de `rl`, que já foi demonstrada no primeiro exemplo.</sup>

---

Uma curiosidade é que o [Deno](https://deno.land), ao contrário do Node.js, implementa o `prompt` ([veja aqui](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#prompt)). Isso provavelmente se deve já que o Deno atribui grande importância à manutenção de maior compatibilidade com os padrões já estabelecidos na web.

Comment: E pode usar o `AbortController` para adicionar um tempo limite, assim que um setTimeout (por exemplo) passar o tempo, executaria o `.abort()`, apesar de nada ter a ver com a necessidade básica da pergunta, só para mencionar mesmo.... Fora isso também é interessante adicionar o `SIGINT` (`rl.on('SIGINT', ....);`) para controlar quando houver um `Ctrl+C`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma biblioteca chamada 'prompt-sync', ficaria assim.
Digite `npm install prompt-sync` no terminal pra instalar os módulos da biblioteca.

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')
const prompt = prompt()

var distance = prompt("Digite aqui a distância");

if (distance >= 6 && distance <= 800008) {
    console.log("distância aprovada");
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).