# Como fazer input de dados no Nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Atualmente iniciei um curso de Javascript usando Nodejs, como faço para realizar um input de dados pelo usuário ?
Anteriormente estudei um pouco de Python, no python é simples:

dados = input("digite aqui sua idade:")

Mas em javaScript com Node?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Node.js - Como ler input do usuário pelo console?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286546/node-js-como-ler-input-do-usu%c3%a1rio-pelo-console)

Comment: Ou [Como pedir entrada do usuário em Node.js?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/513684/como-pedir-entrada-do-usu%c3%a1rio-em-node-js/513687#513687)

Answer (score 0):

Para obter input do utilizador com NodeJS existe o pacote 'prompt'. Para instalar usa-se o comando `npm install prompt`. O código é o seguinte:

```
var prompt = require('prompt');

prompt.start();
prompt.get(['input1'], function (err, result) {
    console.log(result.input1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

O node possui um `módulo` nativo que trata as inserções de comando via *terminal ( prompt )*. Esse módulo é o `readline`, através dele basta instânciá-lo.

```
const readline = require("readline");
```

Configura-lo para receber a entrada e utilizar a sáida do seu terminal.

```
const leitor = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
```

É utilizar a função `question` que irá imprimir a sua `pergunta/texto` e esperar uma resposta dentro do `callback` da função.

```
leitor.question('Qual o seu nome? ', (resposta) => {
  
    console.log(`Seja bem-vindo: ${reposta}`);
    leitor.close()
  
});
```

se você quiser saber mais sobre esse módulo do nodejs é só dar uma olhada na [`documentação`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/readline.html)