# Como capturar um valor para uma variável no Javascript?

Tags: javascript, portugol

No Portugol é possível capturar valores de forma bem simples, como exemplo:

```
função Inicio()
{
    Inteiro A
    Escreva("Digite o valor de A: ")
    leia(A)
}
```

Agora queria saber se isso existe dentro do Javascript, mas pra aplicar dentro do terminal e não com um input do html.

Espero que tenham entendido minha duvida

Comment: deve ser [prompt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)

Comment: `function Inicio() {
    let A;
    A = parseInt(prompt("Digite o valor de A: "));
    alert('O valor de A é: '+A);
}`

Answer (score -3):

Buscando um pouco, encontrei esse link: [Node.js - Como ler input do usuário pelo console?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/286546/node-js-como-ler-input-do-usu%C3%A1rio-pelo-console)

Nesse primeiro método, ele usa uma biblioteca chamada readline, funcionando muito bem pelos poucos testes que fiz.

Ou, caso você não veja problema em usar um `alert()` em um navegador, o que não irá precisar usar html, você pode consultar esse site: [https://sebhastian.com/javascript-console-input/#:~:text=Getting%20user%20input%20from%20the,const%20input%20%3D%20prompt()%3B](https://sebhastian.com/javascript-console-input/#:%7E:text=Getting%20user%20input%20from%20the,const%20input%20%3D%20prompt()%3B), nele o autor explica como usar códigos no console do navegador, para pedir inputs ao usuário.